# MergeSort a vector using Iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, mergesort

For a class assignment, I am required to mergeSort a vector using its iterators.

I wrote the following that works on vectors, but does not use iterators:

```
void MergeSort(IntVector &vec, int left, int right)
{
     if (left < right)
     { 
          int nMid = ((left + right) / 2);
          MergeSort(vec, left, nMid);
          MergeSort(vec, nMid + 1, right);

          //merge(vec, left, nMid, right);
     }
}
```

I tried making some changes to accomodate iterators, but it doesn't allow me to perform operations such as < and + on iterators.

```
void MergeSort(IntVectorIt left, IntVectorIt right)
{
     if (left < right)
     { 
          intVectorIt nMid = ((left + right) / 2);
          MergeSort(left, mid);
          MergeSort(mid + 1, right);

          //merge(vec, left, nMid, right);
     }
}
```

How can I accomodate the use of Iterators in my mergesort?

FYI, these are the typedefs I use:

```
typedef vector<int> IntVector;
typedef IntVector::iterator IntVectorIt;
```

Comment: Be careful about using iterators, some operations on vector will invalidate the iterators and cause undefined behavior. See here:http://learningcppisfun.blogspot.com/2007/01/vector-iterator-invalidation.html

Comment: unfortunately the professor insists that our merge sort use the STL merge (algorithms.h), and that merge only works with vectors and iterators.

Comment: as you present it, I don't see any problems--you can't insert/remove to/from the vector because you only have access to two iterators, but just thought I'd warn you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *want* to compare if the iterators are the same (only error condition possible with sane input):

```
 if (left!=right)
```

As for your addition concerns, you're thinking of it wrong. Semantically adding `left` and `right` makes no sense since it goes past the end of your array, not to mention it will overflow. What you want is to add half the distance between them to `left`:

```
IntVectorIt nMid=left+(right-left)/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `left<right`, you have to use `*left<*right`.

Comment: but wouldn't *left equate to the value in the vector that left points to? I don't want to check the values, but I want to check if the left iterator is to the left of the right Iterator?

Comment: @xbonez: Ah, sorry I misread your question. In that case `left!=right` would be more appropriate.